sending modal after series of select menu
so my slash command is an interactive one where users input a series of selections in a step-by-step process, and in one step i want to send a modal but as it goes, i cant do it through the traditional way of interaction.response.send_modal as the interaction has already been responded to. Does anyone know of any solution? I have seen other bots do it. Infact, the famous atlas bot where you can make custom actions/commands does it. I initially made my command in that bot and it sends modal after responding and editing the interaction multiple times, unfortunately code in that bot are in forms of tags.
P.S. this is my first question in stack, so i apologize for any fault at posting the question
Honestly, I'm clueless about what to try. I looked throughout the internet and other posts in stack, but none helps or gives the actual solution. They all say that it's not possible, but as I mentioned i have seen other bots do this. Another time i saw this was in a ticket system

Can you post your current code?
And do you want the select menus to be in the same view? (Means they all show up at the same time) or do you want them to show up one another. My bot can do both scenarios so I should be able to help.

Hello! Thanks for the response. I was able to edit the select menu views and prompt them to the user one after the other using interaction.edit_original_message(view=new_view). What I was not able to do was send a modal in the same way, but removing interaction.response.defer() and then just normally using interaction.response.send_modal() have fixed the issue of Interaction already responded !
